# Using params in rails gives ArgumentError: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-hash

I am using params which is a hash and still, I get this error stating ArgumentError (When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.) Here are parts of my code:

**Project/app/controllers/index_controller.rb:**

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
    helper_method :create
    def create
        @post = Post.new(params[:data_value])
    end
end
```

**Project/app/models/post.rb:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :posts, :dependent => :delete_all
end
```

**Project/config/routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "index#index"
  post "/customurl", to: "index#create"
end
```

ajax request from **Project/app/assets/javascripts/index.js:**

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/customurl",
    type : "post",
    data : { data_value: "Hello" }
})
```

When I print the return value of `create` method from views, it displays a random hex value for each call. Can anyone please help me by letting me know what's the mistake I am doing.

Comment: Can you update the question with `params` that are coming in the server log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass `params[:data_value]` to the Post object. From your script it looks like `params[:data_value]` equals `"Hello"`. Instead `Post.create` expects a hash.

You should either do `Post.create(params)` or `Post.create(data_value: params[:data_value])`. Also, check out https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters to make your parameters secure.

Comment: You are spot on!

Comment: I am getting `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` when I do, 
`post = Post.create(params)`

Comment: Yes, `Post.create(params)` was a bad example. Try to extract values from `params`. e.g. `Post.create(data_value: params[:data_value])`.

Comment: But first, I strongly advise to read about strong parameters. It will also helps to handle this issue with params.